# Как правильно прописать json структуру в models.py. при работе с MongoDB

Tags: python, django, json, mongodb

БД моего проекта - MongoDB, для соединения mongo и проекта django я использую движок "djongo".

Есть следующая структура json которую необходимо добавить в models.py моего проекта django:

```
"make": {
      "1_new": 21,
      "2_new": 16,
      "right": 80,
      "left": 10,
      },
   "static": [
      {
         "name": " 1",
         "number": 1,
         "id":93,
         "day": {
            "start": 7,
            "end": 23,
            "personal": false,
            "_on": false,
            "_off": false,
            "ors": [
               {"name": "камни",
                "number": 1,
                "status": true}
```

Подскажите, как мне это правильно описать? Могу ли я использовать такой же формат, если да то помогите пожалуйста примером.

Comment: Django-модели отражают структуры таблиц SQL, а таблицы это просто строки и столбцы без каких-либо вложений объектов друг в друга. Так что вам, видимо, придётся пихать всё в один JSONField или типа того

Comment: @andreymal, можете показать на примере, как выглядит?

Comment: JSONField удалили с 4 версии https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#features-removed-in-4-0
Вариант превратить все в модели, если структура известна и сериализовать
Еще вариант, если очень надо, воспользоваться MongoDB

Comment: @maestro, никаких других методов нет кроме сериализации? Может я могу обойти вооббще работу с моделями с помощью библиотеки pymongo?

Comment: @maestro, в прикрепленной Вами статье указано, что удалены django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField и django.contrib.postgres.forms.JSONField, но разве они не относятся к взаимодействию только с postgres?

Comment: К сожалению, не вижу в описании вопроса БД которая используется, на сколько мне известно в sqlite вообще не было никогда JSONField, а для джанго приложения обычно используют именно постгрю. 
так какая бд используется?

Comment: @maestro, я работаю с mongodb

Comment: Django в принципе не умеет работать с MongoDB, так что теперь вопрос стал совершенно непонятен

Comment: не, к джанге можно подключить любую базу, я с монго не работал, так, ради эксперемента пробовал на фласке подключиться, первая ссылка в гугле дала https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-and-django как раз то что вы дополнили в вопросе djongo и pymongo,  просто подключаетесь к бд и сохраняете весь json, просто надо настроить для себя структуру обьектов, что бы потом можно было понятным образом достать json обратно. По ссылке есть конкретный пример использования

Comment: @maestro djongo не является официальной частью Django

Comment: и что? это сторонняя библиотека как и drf напрмиер тот же, pytest, это разве проблема?